# MySQL query for month year

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table with following fields

```
id (int)
name (varchar)
dob (datetime)
```

Now I need a query that can match month and year at same time

What I am using right now is

```
select * from users where month(dob)='12' and year(dob)='2010'
```

I don't want to use month() and year(), can it be done in single thing?

Help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be expressed as you request, but I don't think it would be any more efficient.

```
where dob >= '2010-12-01' and dob <= '2010-12-31 23:59:59'
```

or

```
where '201012' = date_format(dob,'%Y%m')
```

Comment: @I-M-JM: But using DATE_FORMAT means that an index, if there is one on the dob column, could not be used -- not good.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from users where dob >= '2010-12-01' and dob < '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: you can't really get better then that. what are you looking for?