# Default datetime format in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime-format

I'm coding to search data by compare `dateTime`. In web form, user input value `2012-06-04` store in `$_REQUEST['dateSearch']`. I create `dateTime` object from that:

```
$dateObj = date_create_from_format("Y-m-d",$_REQUEST['dateSearch']);
$dateParam = $dateObj->format("Y-m");
```

Then I use `$dateParam` in sql query to find data

```
$sql = "
    SELECT *
    FROM `temp` as `t`
    WHERE `t`.`date` LIKE '$dateParam%'
";
```

Everything is ok, but I'm not sure MySQL alway use only one `dateTime` format `Y-m-d H:i:s`. 
At here, `$dateParam = $dateObj->format("Y-m");` I set default format is "Y-m". Is the default format never change? I don't want hard set format `Y-m-d H:i:s` in code, instead of, I think get format string from system to use is better. How do I get default `dateTime` format string from mySQL???

Comment: BTW, `LIKE '$dateParam%'` is a pretty inefficient search method, since it searches by comparing text values. `WHERE YEAR(date) = 2012 AND MONTH(date) = 6` will probably be more performant, since it allows MySQL to use its native date format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand, `Y-m-d H:i:s`
is the **ONLY** format for **datetime** data type.

```
Y-m-d = date
H:i:s = time
```

That's why is named as `datetime`

To change the return format for datetime in mysql,
you can use [date_format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) function in mysql

Such as,

```
date_format('%Y-%m') = 2012-06
```

Comment: thank you! I'm realize I should force mySQL play with our rule by DATE_FORMAT(). Thanks.

Comment: What if I want set default datetime format in MySQL  to 'Y/m/d H:i:s'? Is it possible?

Comment: What would you want to do this? Data formatting should be done at the user interface that consume the data.

Answer (score 0):

Better use below!

```
select * from users where month(`t`.`date`)='12' and year(`t`.`date`)='2010'
```

REF: [MySQL query for month year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406124/mysql-query-for-month-year)